# implicit conversion from lower to higher

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit

I have the following function that finds the minimum sum of 4 numbers and that maximum one:

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr)
{
    std::sort (arr.begin(), arr.end());           //(12 32 45 71)26 80 53 33
    unsigned long long minSum = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3];
    unsigned long long maxSum = (unsigned long long) arr[arr.size() - 1] + (unsigned long long) arr[arr.size() - 2] + (unsigned long long) arr[arr.size() - 3];
    cout << arr[arr.size() - 1] << " " << arr[arr.size() - 2] << " " << arr[arr.size() - 3] << " " << arr[arr.size() - 4] << " " << endl;
    cout << minSum << " " << maxSum << endl;
}
```

Now, if I omit the (unsigned long long) conversions I get an overflow. Does anyone know why? Shouldn't the compiler convert the int to unsigned long long automatically?

Comment: When you add two `int`s you get the resulting number as `int`. Imagine two INT_MAX numbers adding, the resulting will be an Intger, where the overflow already happened.  The implicit conversion to `unsigned long long`(`maxSum`) is happening after this overflow. Hence, you need to cast the integers to higher types, before you add them together.

Comment: you just need to cast one of the operands, no need to do that to all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the comments! The answer is given above by @JeJo. More specifically:

If we omit all the (unsigned long long) conversions, then the result of the add operation will be an integer (overflowed) and subsequently is going to be converted on unsigned long long. To prevent overflow, we just have to keep one of the (unsigned long long) casts, because that way one of the adding numbers is ULL, and the other parts of the add operation will be converted too. Thus the result of the add operation will be an unsigned long long number.